# SQL query to get regularly payment date

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to write a SQL query to get which customers had paying their bills regularly and which has not.
the table is in ORACLE.

```
CUSTOMERS table.
customers_id   customers_name   bill_value    payment_date
----------------------------------------------------------
001            ary              30000         1/14/2012
001            ary              30000         2/14/2012
001            ary              30000         3/14/2012
001            ary              30000         4/14/2012
002            budhy            25000         1/21/2012
002            budhy            25000         2/25/2012
002            budhy            25000         3/21/2012
002            budhy            25000         4/23/2012
003            chanadh          51000         1/17/2012
003            chanadh          51000         2/17/2012
003            chanadh          51000         3/17/2012
003            chanadh          51000         4/17/2012
```

question is..

first, I wanna display **customers who had paying their bills regulary**, the result that i expected like this..

```
customers_id   customers_name   bill_value    payment_date
----------------------------------------------------------
001            ary              30000         1/14/2012
001            ary              30000         2/14/2012
001            ary              30000         3/14/2012
001            ary              30000         4/14/2012
003            chanadh          51000         1/17/2012
003            chanadh          51000         2/17/2012
003            chanadh          51000         3/17/2012
003            chanadh          51000         4/17/2012
```

second, i wanna display **customers who had NOT paying their bills regulary**, the result that i expected like this..

```
customers_id   customers_name   bill_value    payment_date
----------------------------------------------------------
002            budhy            25000         1/21/2012
002            budhy            25000         2/25/2012
002            budhy            25000         3/21/2012
002            budhy            25000         4/23/2012
```

now i still stuck with the query,i cannot figure it how to do it, 
can anyone help pls?

sorry for my english

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer about what "regularly" means. If ary had paid on 2/13/2012 i.e. early, is that still regular?

Comment: when ary paid on 2/13/2012 then its not "regular" anymore. What i mean regullary is that day-date is still same, like ary always paid on every 14th for each month.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

**customers who had paying their bills regulary**

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT A.*,COUNT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(day from to_date(payment_date,'mm/dd/yyyy'))) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY customers_id) cnt
  FROM TEST A
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE CNT = 1;
```

**customers who had NOT paying their bills regulary**

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT A.*,COUNT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(day from to_date(payment_date,'mm/dd/yyyy'))) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY customers_id) cnt
  FROM TEST A
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE CNT > 1;
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6e2b/9)

Comment: its works ! but i have to remove to_date function coz the payment_date field already date type. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
select this.*, next.payment_date next_payment_date
from CUSTOMERS this
join CUSTOMERS next on next.customers_id = this.customers_id 
and next.payment_date = (select min(payment_date) from CUSTOMERS where customers_id = this.customers_id and payment_date>this.payment_date)
where trunc(add_months(this.payment_date,1)) < trunc(next.payment_date)
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/007e0/4

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT
  y.*, 
  (CASE WHEN PD=CN THEN 'Regular' ELSE 'Irregular' END) Status
FROM (
    SELECT
      x.*,
      count(*) over (partition by CUSTOMERS_ID, EXTRACT(day FROM payment_date)) PD,
      count(*) over (partition by CUSTOMERS_ID) CN
    FROM CUSTOMERS x
)y;
```